# Can we send multiple responses in intervals to a single request, Using Django as server?

Tags: python, django, rest

I am just working on an app, which sends a request to the server asking it to report the details of a device every 10 seconds for the next 60 seconds. I am using Django framework as the backend server. Can we send multiple responses to a single request from the app? If yes, Can you point me in the right direction.

Comment: Run WebSocket in any way you want or just make 6 requests with a time delay of 10 secs.

Comment: Are you using a browser as a client or something else?

Comment: I am using android app as my client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not It is not possible my friend .. because it is not related to Django or other web framework .. that's Http Rules and you can't change Them ..
Every http request has only one http response  ..

Comment: Sorry, but the HTTP servers may send one or more informational responses  (100 Continue, for example) before the main response. (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.2)

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively new concept called [channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). which is suitable for the job.